# php cURL giving blank response body

Tags: php, curl, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I am getting a blank response body on the following cURL request, but only on one machine (osx running two vagrant boxes) .  I've checked and rechecked the project code is there, and it indeed works on all other machines I've used.. except ONE.  Any ideas?

My Call in PHP is to `POSTRequestTrusted(/api/login, <some_json_data>`

```
public static function POSTRequestTrusted($service_name, $data) {

  self::checkApiKey(); //checks the key is set

  return self::execCURLRequest("POST", $service_name, array('Content-Type: application/json',
          'Accept: application/json',
          'Authorization: Basic ' . self::$apiKey )
      , $data);
}

public static function execCURLRequest($type, $service_name = null, $custom_headers = null, $data = null) {

  //If the verb is unexpected, throw exception
  if($type !== "GET"
      and $type!== "POST"
      and $type!== "DELETE"
      and $type!== "PUT"
      and $type!== "PATCH" ) 
    { return -1 ;}

  //If calling a service, or just pinging the base hostname:port
  if($service_name !== null) {
    $full_url = self::$apiBase . $service_name;
  } else {
    $full_url = self::$apiBase;
  }

  // initialize cURL
  $ch = curl_init($full_url);

  // SET the HTTP VERB type, unless it's a POST which doesn't require anything
  if($type == 'PUT' or $type == 'DELETE' or $type == 'PATCH'){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $type);
  } else if ($type == 'GET'){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
  }
  //Flag needed to return response
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  // custom headers are needed for testing trusted client calls.
  if($custom_headers !== null){
    $full_header = $custom_headers;
  } else {
    $full_header = self::$STD_HEADER;
  }

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $full_header); //Set the Header
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // return headers?

  // If data was present, encode it and append to request
  if($data !== null){
    $json_data = json_encode($data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
  }

  $response = curl_exec ($ch);

  // parse the entire response, down to the header and body
  list($response_header, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);

  $response_body = json_decode($body);

  curl_close ($ch);

  return array($response_header, $response_body);
```

Output :

`HTTP\\/1.1 200 OK\\r\\nDate: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 22:41:46 GMT\\r\\nServer: Apache\\/2.4.9 (Ubuntu)\\r\\nX-Powered-By: PHP\\/5.5.13-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1\\r\\nCache-Control: no-store\\r\\nPragma: no-cache\\r\\nContent-Length: 174\\r\\nContent-Type: application\\/json",null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $response_body = json_decode($body);

  curl_close ($ch);

  return array($response_header, $response_body);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

> #### Return Values
>
> Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL respectively. **NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.**

You should check what the body returned actually is, because it's not decoding properly. The content-length header you've gotten back say you should have 174 bytes of *something*.

Comment: I'll look into that, however I'd wonder why my requests were working when on other machines.. and they all are running via Vagrant..

Comment: The json_decode is behaving differently .. even though I've got the system out of vagrant.. this is bizarre

Comment: turns out it was the BOM, which I need to strip before running JSON_DECODE... http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.pack.php